# Replace values of a DataFrame using Scala's API

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I need to replace some values in a `Column` of a `DataFrame` (nulls and zeros for the mode, I know this approach isn't very accurate but I am just practicing). I'm proficient with the `Python` documentation of Apache Spark, and the examples tend to be more explanatory. Therefore, I decided to take a look over there first, besides the Scala documentation, and I noticed that it's possible to achieve what I need using the [replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=replace#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace) method from `DataFrames`.

In this example I replace all `2` to `20` in the column `col`.

`df = df.replace("2", "20", subset="col")`

After getting some confidence with the `Python` API, I decided to replicate this on `Scala`, and I noticed some strange things in the `Scala` doc. Firstly, apparently `DataFrames` don't have the method `replace`. Secondly, after some research I noticed I have to use the `replace` functionality of [DataFrameNaFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions), but this is the rare part, if you see the details of that method you will notice that they use this functionality the same way as in the `python` implementation (see image below).

[image: replace documentation]

After this, I tried to run this in Scala and exploded, showing the next error:

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:108: error: value replace is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
                  val dx = df.replace(column, Map(0.0 -> doubleValue))
                              ^
StackTrace:
```

Then I tried to apply the `replace` using the `DataFrameNaFunctions`, but I can't make it to work as easy as in `python`, because I got an error and I don't understand why.

```
val dx = df.na.replace(column, Map(0.0 -> doubleValue))
```

Here comes the error:

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:108: error: overloaded method value replace with alternatives:
  [T](cols: Seq[String], replacement: scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,T])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  [T](col: String, replacement: scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,T])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  [T](cols: Array[String], replacement: java.util.Map[T,T])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  [T](col: String, replacement: java.util.Map[T,T])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (String, scala.collection.mutable.Map[Double,Double])
                  val dx = df.na.replace(column, Map(0.0 -> doubleValue))
                                 ^
```

Comment: It works if I do `Map(0.0 -> doubleValue).toMap`, but it is not exposed in the documentation. :|

Comment: Your second attempt should work, but just as error says you should use `immutable.Map` instead of `mutable.Map`.
Generally you should avoid mutable collections when working with spark

Comment: I.e. just import `Map` from the right place : `scala.collection.immutable`

Comment: @Odomontois So when I use `Map`, it loads the class from the `mutable` package?

Comment: You can read about packages [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/119.html). By default `Map` is bound to `immutable.Map` as seen [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/index.html#scala.Predef$). But I guess you have some unwanted import somewhere above.

Comment: @Odomontois However do you know why the documentation shows an example which actually doesn't work? i.e. It says `df.replace` instead of `df.na.replace`

Comment: `df` is just free symbol to bound. Why for example you shouldn't write `val df = myDataFrame.na` and then use as `df.replace`. You can't say it doesn't work, but it could be misleading. [You are always welcomed to fix such things](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Contributing+to+Spark)

Comment: @Odomontois Yes, but it confounds me, even more when you had already used the `Python` API.

Comment: Either a mistake from the beginning or an artifact of some long forgotten implicant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that I imported some libraries from the `mutable`  package, so I just needed to execute the method `.toMap` to convert it to `immutable`.

```
val dx = df.na.replace(column, Map(0.0 -> doubleValue))
```